# Avoiding multiple unique divs in single page CSS

Tags: html, css

I have would like to combine all my CSS files into a single file to lessen the load on the server, however, I use quite a number of divs with the same name on the page, but they are styled differently.

How do I style the single page CSS to specify that this section is for X.html only and what do I need to add in the X.html?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to do with class name. Need to assign different different class name according to page.

Comment: If they are diferent for every controller, you can add class to body html tag like: <body class="contact">

Comment: Use the different class in html. And add the different styles as per class in your css file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give each page an id and then target that id and div specifically.  For example

Page one:

```
<body id="page-one">
   <div class="content"></div>
</body>
```

Page two:

```
<body id="page-two">
   <div class="content"></div>
</body>
```

and then styles like

```
#page-one .content {background:red;}
#page-two .content {background:blue;}
```

Comment: You can use [scoped css](https://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/) but his only seems to work in firefox: http://caniuse.com/#search=scoped%20css